# Is there a reason why sbt does not support the developer key?

Tags: scala, maven, sbt, metadata

This would allow to minimize the pomExtra key that is required in every project that is deployed to maven central.

This link explains how you can use the sbt license and url homepage key to minize the pomExtra but I am curious why sbt does not have an equivalent for all the keys so that we could avoid this whole pomExtra thing.

http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Using-Sonatype.html

Comment: No.  Please open a feature ticket.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since SBT `0.13.7` the developer key is supported, eg:

`developers := List(Developer("benhutchison", "Ben Hutchison", "bhutchison@email.com", url = url("https://github.com/benhutchison")))`

will result in

`<developers>
        <developer>
            <id>benhutchison</id>
            <name>Ben Hutchison</name>
            <email>bhutchison@email.com</email>
            <url>https://github.com/benhutchison</url>
        </developer>
    </developers>`

Comment: Oh, awesome. Thx for the answer. I'm actually the one who added it!